# Oracle 11g - What can replace Fetch next 1 rows only

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[image: Table 1]
This is my table. (Table 1)

[image: Table 2]
This is the expected result. (Table 2)

[image: Table 3]
This is what I get for now. (Table 3)

For example, I want to get 40 of the quantity. The result should as table 2 but I get table 3. Running_total must equal or more than the quantity requested.

```
select  id, quantity, running_total  from 
( 
select id, quantity, sum(quantity) over (partition by id ) running_total from table 
) 
where running_total <= 40;
```

This is my code.
After research, I found Offset and Fetch may acquire the result in table 2 but I'm using Oracle 11g. (11g doesn't support offset and fetch)

```
select  id, quantity, running_total  from 
( 
select id, quantity, sum(quantity) over (partition by id ) running_total from table 
) 
where running_total <= 40
Offset 0 rows fetch next 1 rows only;
```

Anything can replace fetch next 1 rows only or any way else to get the result?
Thanks.

Comment: A running total without an `ORDER BY` doesn't make much sense. A `FETCH` clause without an `ORDER BY` doesn't either. Can you please show by what column you want your data ordered? And why is the table's ID always the same value? A table's ID should be unique. And how can your result be several rows, when you apply `FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS`? It should be *one* row then.

Comment: And if you want a value greater than 40, then neither of your queries can work, because `where running_total <= 40` selects values **not** greater than 40.

Comment: As to the real task: It seems you want to add up values until you reach fourty and then show this number. This can be fourty or any value higher than fourty, depending on the last added value. In your example you want to show 44 for ID 1. But what if for an ID you never reach fourty? Do you want to show this ID still? With its sum which is below fourty? Or do you want to suppress this ID then? Do you want to show the one value per ID or do you want to show all those rows per ID until fourty is reached?

Comment: Hi, this table is just for demonstration. In the actual table my part_number are unique. In this situation, what else you will suggest me to code my query in order to get the result?

Comment: For an example, a bakery need 40 packs of biscuit (any brand). In store, Brand A have 10 packs, Brand B have 20 packs, Brand C have 5 packs and Brand D have 10 packs.

Comment: The result should come out with Brand A, B, C, D (45 packs). If the result only come out with Brand A, B, C, which means that only 35 packs of biscuit (not enough).

I'm very sorry if I confused you because this is the only way I can think to explain it to you.

Comment: I faced the same situation here. When the technician needs 40 of that raw material (from any supplier) the system should shows which raw material the technician should take first (order by purchase date (old first new later)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the quantity from the running total in your comparison:

```sql
select id,
       quantity,
       running_total
from   ( 
  select id,
         quantity,
         sum(quantity) over (
           partition by id
           ORDER BY dt
         ) AS running_total
  from   table_name
) 
where running_total - quantity < 40;
```

*(Note: In SQL rows are unordered so you need to provide some way of ordering the rows; I've added a `DT` column to provide this ordering.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, quantity, dt ) AS
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 20, DATE '2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  5, DATE '2020-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  1, DATE '2020-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  8, DATE '2020-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 30, DATE '2020-01-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, DATE '2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, DATE '2020-01-03' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | QUANTITY | RUNNING_TOTAL
> -: | -------: | ------------:
>  1 |       10 |            10
>  1 |       20 |            30
>  1 |        5 |            35
>  1 |        1 |            36
>  1 |        8 |            44
>  2 |       20 |            20
>  2 |       20 |            40
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4c8861dd5a9e5e1e5108dce6c726b34)*

Comment: Ah, so simple :-) It must be `where running_total - quantity < 40`, though.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks. I'd just worked that out too and was just updating the db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly now, you want to show all rows till you reach at least 40. With

```
+------------+----------+---------+
| product_id | quantity | sortkey |
+------------+----------+---------+
|          1 |       10 |       1 |
|          1 |       20 |       2 |
|          1 |       30 |       3 |
|          1 |       40 |       4 |
|          1 |       50 |       5 |
|          2 |       20 |       1 |
|          2 |       20 |       2 |
|          2 |       20 |       3 |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

You would want to show

```
+------------+----------+---------+-------+
| product_id | quantity | sortkey | total |
+------------+----------+---------+-------+
|          1 |       10 |       1 |    10 |
|          1 |       20 |       2 |    30 |
|          1 |       30 |       3 |    60 |
|          2 |       20 |       1 |    20 |
|          2 |       20 |       2 |    40 |
+------------+----------+---------+-------+
```

because with 60 you have finally reached 40 for product #1, while for product #2 you reach 40 exactly.

This is difficult, because you cannot limit the result to `<= 40`, because you may want the first value `> 40`, too. (For product #1 you do, for product #2 you don't.)

This would be my approach: Show all rows with a total `< 40` and the first row with a total `>= 40`.

```
select product_id, quantity, sortkey, total
from
(
  select
    product_id, quantity, sortkey, total,
    min(case when total >= 40 then total end) over (partition by product_id) as reached
  from
  (
    select
      product_id, quantity, sortkey,
      sum(quantity) over (partition by product_id order by sortkey) as total
    from mytable
  )
)
where total < 40 or total = reached
order by product_id, sortkey;
```